# Is there a more elegant formula/method to write a macro line to reformat addresses in VBA/excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, crm

I'm new to VBA so please bear with me. I recently built a macro that re-formats donor and donation data from a csv (downloaded regularly from an online donation platform) into a format that's import-able into our main database.

So I'm working with really annoying "people" data, like addresses, phone numbers, names, etc. made more annoying by the fact that the data in the csv download is entered by donors themselves.

I wrote a ***very long*** formula (see below) that is meant to fix the format of **addresses** (to the best of my ability), but I'm imagining there's a much more succinct (*~*elegant*~*) way to write it specifically using vba functions instead of excel.

I've been using the text entry for the formulas thus far (example below; I've defined **Lastrow** and would like the formulas to stop there and this method seemed to be a bit easier) however, I've seen recommendations against this method, so I'm open to changing that for this monster.

```
Range("F2:F" & Lastrow).Formula = "=PROPER(TRIM(M2))"
```

The formula exploded in length because of the following:

- There are 2 columns for street address that need to be merged into
  one for the import format. I used TEXTJOIN(). However...

  - If the second column is an apartment, suite, etc, the delimiter should be a comma and a space ", "
  - If the first column is a building name and the second is a street address, the delimiter should be a carriage return CHAR(10).
- The second thing is capitalization (because people enter their own address in funky ways). I used the PROPER() formula. However, there are a few weird nuances

  - Streets that have NE, NW, SW, and SE end up wrong: Ne, Nw, Sw, Se
  - Streets that have 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. end up wrong: 1St, 2Nd, 3Rd, 4Th, etc. *(I have yet to include a fix for these addresses because the formula is already humongous and this step is making me question if it's the best way - which is why I'm posting this)*.

```
IFS(
    AND(
        OR(
            LEFT(U2,1)=""#"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""apt"",
            LEFT(U2,9)=""apartment"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""bldg"",
            LEFT(U2,8)=""building"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""fl"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" fl"",U2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" floor"",U2)),
            LEFT(U2,5)=""floor"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""ste"",
            LEFT(U2,5)=""suite"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""unit"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""rm"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""room""
        ),
        OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" NW"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Nw"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" nw"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" NW "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Nw "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" nw "",T2))
        )
    ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,T2,U2))),""Nw"",""NW""),
    AND(
        OR(
            LEFT(U2,1)=""#"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""apt"",
            LEFT(U2,9)=""apartment"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""bldg"",
            LEFT(U2,8)=""building"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""fl"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" fl"",U2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" floor"",U2)),
            LEFT(U2,5)=""floor"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""ste"",
            LEFT(U2,5)=""suite"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""unit"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""rm"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""room""
        ),
        OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" NE"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Ne"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" ne"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" NE "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Ne "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" ne "",T2))
        )
    ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,T2,U2))),""Ne"",""NE""),    
    AND(
        OR(
            LEFT(U2,1)=""#"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""apt"",
            LEFT(U2,9)=""apartment"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""bldg"",
            LEFT(U2,8)=""building"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""fl"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" fl"",U2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" floor"",U2)),
            LEFT(U2,5)=""floor"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""ste"",
            LEFT(U2,5)=""suite"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""unit"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""rm"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""room""
        ),
        OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" SW"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Sw"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" sw"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" SW "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Sw "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" sw "",T2))
        )
    ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,T2,U2))),""Sw"",""SW""),
    AND(
        OR(
            LEFT(U2,1)=""#"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""apt"",
            LEFT(U2,9)=""apartment"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""bldg"",
            LEFT(U2,8)=""building"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""fl"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" fl"",U2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" floor"",U2)),
            LEFT(U2,5)=""floor"",
            LEFT(U2,3)=""ste"",
            LEFT(U2,5)=""suite"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""unit"",
            LEFT(U2,2)=""rm"",
            LEFT(U2,4)=""room""
        ),
        OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" SE"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Se"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" se"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" SE "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Se "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" se "",T2))
        )
    ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,T2,U2))),""Se"",""SE""),
    OR(
        LEFT(U2,1)=""#"",
        LEFT(U2,3)=""apt"",
        LEFT(U2,9)=""apartment"",
        LEFT(U2,4)=""bldg"",
        LEFT(U2,8)=""building"",
        LEFT(U2,2)=""fl"",
        ISNUMBER(FIND("" fl"",U2)),
        ISNUMBER(FIND("" floor"",U2)),
        LEFT(U2,5)=""floor"",
        LEFT(U2,3)=""ste"",
        LEFT(U2,5)=""suite"",
        LEFT(U2,4)=""unit"",
        LEFT(U2,2)=""rm"",
        LEFT(U2,4)=""room""
    ),
    PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,T2,U2))),
    OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" NW"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Nw"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" nw"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" NW "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Nw "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" nw "",T2))
        ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,T2,U2))),""Nw"",""NW""),
    OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" NE"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Ne"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" ne"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" NE "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Ne "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" ne "",T2))
        ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,T2,U2))),""Ne"",""NE""),
    OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" SW"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Sw"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" sw"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" SW "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Sw "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" sw "",T2))
        ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,T2,U2))),""Sw"",""SW""),
    OR(
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" SE"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" Se"",
            RIGHT(T2,3)="" se"",
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" SE "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" Se "",T2)),
            ISNUMBER(FIND("" se "",T2))
        ),
    SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,T2,U2))),""Se"",""SE""),
    TRUE,
    PROPER(TRIM(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,T2,U2)))
)
```

Comment: This really doesn't look like something you'd want to do in a VBA macro; rather, you'd want to use an actual geocoding service that can standardize addresses from user-entered text. [Google's API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) is relatively straight-forward to use. They give you a $200 credit each month, so you can make up to 40,000 calls a month without getting charged. There are also totally free alternatives out there, although quality may vary. People use such services for a reason though; standardization is _hard_.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case - thanks so much! I'll look into that!